# Playwright - get a collection of elements

Tags: element, playwright

I want to write a test against a web page that returns a bunch of data in a simple HTML table. One of the columns is an order number - so I want to get a list of order numbers. In Selenium, this is really simple 
`Elements _elements = Driver.FindElements(Map.OrderNumbers.FoundBy);`

where "Map.OrderNumbers" is a simple XPath expression. I tried to use the Playwright equivalent

`const orderNumbers = await page.$$(Map.OrderNumbers)`

but this is not working - it just gives me a lot of useless GUIDs and Element handles. I only want an array of numbers. I tried searching everywhere for examples but have found none.

Comment: You can pass an XPath expression to the $$ function.

Answer (score 0):

[`page.$$()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageselector-1) returns a promise of element handles, this is expected behaviour.

If you need to retrieve some text, or value, you need to do it differently. That depends on a concrete DOM, since you don't share it, it's difficult to help you, but as an example, let's say those elements have a value attribute that you want to retrieve, then this would be a way:

```js
const orderNumbers = await page.$$eval('.myelement', el => el.value);
```

After this, you'd end up with an array of concrete values retrieved from the vlaue attribute of those `.myelement` elements.